# Azure role-based access control user cannot find resource

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

Assigned Azure Custom Vision role to user but unable to access resource.
Errors shown:

1. Subdomain does not map to a resource.
2. Please check if desired resource exists in subscription.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [this official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/cognitive-services-custom-subdomains#:%7E:text=Sign%20in%20to%20the%20Azure,custom%20subdomain%20for%20your%20resource.),

> **Azure Cognitive Services use custom subdomain names for each resource
> created through the Azure portal, Azure Cloud Shell, or Azure CLI.**
> Unlike regional endpoints, which were common for all customers in a
> specific Azure region, custom subdomain names are unique to the
> resource. Custom subdomain names are required to enable features like
> Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for authentication.

So, I suggest you to first create a Custom subdomain name for the resource and then use RBAC user to access it.

Also, make sure the user has either **Owner** or atleast **Contributor** permission for that resource.

Follow below instructions to migrate an existing resource to leverage custom subdomain names:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal and locate the Cognitive Services resource that you'd like to add a custom subdomain name to.
2. In the Overview blade, locate and select Generate Custom Domain Name.
3. This opens a panel with instructions to create a unique custom subdomain for your resource.